Two modes of operation using a single VFD
Basically, I am working on telescope dome automation and have some problem with the dome shutter operation.
I have implemented a manual system using push buttons controlling two 3 phase motor via a single VFD(Micromaster 440). When I press one push button the dome shutter opens until the contactor de-energizes because of the limit switch. Same operation while closing the dome shutter with a different push button.
I have implemented this using two contactors for two different motor(one for opening and another for closing) which are electrically interlocked so that only one motor functions at a time. So far this works fine.
I want to automate this process by keeping this manual operation intact. I want to take the limit switch data to a MCU and based on this send digital control signals(24V) to the VFD without the use of push buttons.
My question is: How do I go about doing this??
Also, I want both to work simultaneously, I mean I can choose when I want auto or manual.
